# reading .txt file contains employees information and printing out them (Java)

Tags: java

Please I need help, I am trying to get my code working properly. The code is supposed to read .txt file with the name A2Q1in.txt" and print out all the information that the file contains by using loadEmployees method. when compile the code I get 2 errors that I do not know how to fix them, please have a look at output at the end of question.

Code:

```
mport java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class A2Q1
{
 public static void main(String[] parms)
 {
   Employee [] employees ;
   String [] array_;
   array_ =  new String [50];
   employees = loadEmployees();
  System.out.println("\nProgram completed normally.");
 }

 public  static Employee[]  loadEmployees()
 {
  Employee[] employees;


  BufferedReader fileIn;
  String inputLine;

  try
  {
   fileIn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("A2Q1in.txt"));
   inputLine = fileIn.readLine();
   while (inputLine != null)
   {
    System.out.println(inputLine);
    inputLine = fileIn.readLine();
   }
   fileIn.close();
  }
  catch (IOException ioe)
  {
   System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
  }
   print String employees(employees);

 }
}

/*********************************************************************/
/*********************************************************************/

class Employee
{


  private String employeecomany;
  private String name;
  private String division;
  private Double wage;

public Employee(String employeecomany, String name, String division, Double wage)
{
  this.employeecomany = employeecomany;
  this.name = name;
  this.division = division;
  this.wage = wage;


}

 public double getWage()
 {
  return getWage;
 }

 public String toString()  
 {
  return String.format("%-10s %3d  $%4.2f  $%5.2f ", employeecomany, name, division, getWage());
 }
}
```

output errors

### 2 errors and 2 warnings found:

### *** Errors ***

```
File: C:\Users\samiralbayati\Desktop\Comp 1020 JAVA assignment 2\A2Q1.java  [line: 39]
Error: Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
File: C:\Users\samiralbayati\Desktop\Comp 1020 JAVA assignment 2\A2Q1.java  [line: 68]
Error: getWage cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Comment: it cannot find getWage variable

Comment: Did you intialized getWage variable?

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the  `print String employees(employees);` and write `return employees;`
and change your code

```
public double getWage()
 {
  return getWage;
 }
```

to

```
 public double getWage()
 {
  return wage;
 }
```

This is because, you did not initialized or declared the `getWage` variable.

Comment: Ok thanks one error has been solved but please can you help with the other error that says " [line: 39]
Error: Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement"

Comment: So insert the ; at line 39

Comment: So the line got error. I think the line print String employees(employees) right? There is no such thing 'print String' in Java. So remove it

Comment: Ok gjman2, when I remove String I get the following error:

[line: 39]
Error: Syntax error on token "employees", = expected after this token

Comment: I mean remove  "print String employees(employees);"

Comment: Ok I did, but I got another error:

 [line: 16]
Error: This method must return a result of type Employee[]

Comment: so it must "return employees", as the return type is Employee[]

Comment: @user2888380, I think you need to go through on Java basic and fundamental especially on method, array, object classes